# How can multiple services re-use the authentication cookie?

Tags: reactjs, okta

I want to understand how a static site with no backend can use okta with other custom API services hosted on other platforms.

Scenerio:

*Website is a angluar/reactjs that is hosted as a "static" website.*

I'm assuming when you authenticate using okta in e.g. react/angular website I am able to store the okta session id in local storage or cookie.

How say I create a web service and host that on heroku, how can I figure out if the user has authenticated or not and re-use the session?

Answer (score 1):

The scenario where you have:

- A JavaScript frontend application, hosted statically
- A backend web service (API), that the JavaScript app makes API requests to

is a classic single-page app (SPA) scenario. The recommended authentication flow is the [OpenID Connect implicit flow](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-implicit-1_0.html).

In plain English, you are:

1. Setting up your JavaScript app to talk to Okta (or another OpenID Connect identity provider)
2. Getting an access token from the identity provider
3. Attaching the access token to an API request to authorize it

Your API service could be running on Heroku, or somewhere else. In your API service code, you have to validate the access token before you decide to accept the request. The API service can go back and talk to the identity provider to determine if the user's access token is still valid.

How the API service validates the token depends on what language you are using to build your API service. But, that's basic idea: the access token is what authorizes the user's requests.